# Can't log in to Server Fault, Super User or MathOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

Right now, on Server Fault, Super User and MathOverflow, I'm not logged in; if I log in with my Stack Exchange username and password, I'm redirected to the home page but I'm still not logged in. I've already emptied the caches. I'm using the latest Safari (13.0.5) on macOS Catalina (10.15.3).

[image]
[image]

I'm still logged in for other domains (e.g. Ask Ubuntu), it might be that the cross-site login isn't working properly.

Comment: It's worse - it's happening on all sites, all browsers. I'm still logged in on this one (Firefox). Goodbye, cruel world ... </jk>

Comment: @Glorfindel can you please try now? (don't close this if so - we're gathering info and appreciate the help)

Comment: @NickCraver thanks, it seems to be working again :)

Comment: can't repro, all sites logged in

Comment: @zixuan apparently it was real enough to get developer response. I mentioned above that I can't reproduce it either, and IIRC it was a geographical issue.